# android samsung GT-19100

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to connect samsung GT-19100 to my windows7 pc for testing.

When i connect via USB, the device is not getting detected.

I am not getting the right link for dowloading the device drivers.

Please help.

Comment: It May be possible that your USB port is disable because of pen drive useage

Comment: my mobile is showing USB connected but on my pc its not detected

Comment: yes that is what I am telling you that your Computer's USB port might be blocked using Registry Settings.

Comment: when i try to connect some other device like sony ericsson its getting detected on the same port . SO do you think it wil be blocked for any particular device . I initially got the message device driver not properly installed. But now no message coming

Comment: okies. so your port is not blocked. good try some other USB port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the driver you can download KIES from this url:
http://www.samsungapps.com/about/onPc.as

if you are using eclipse for testing then you'll need the drivers and you'll need to set your device on debugging mode as follows:

settings>applications>development>usb debugging

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes i had downloaded the PC suite , which didnt have the complete device drivers. Kies is the right software . I did it and the settings u have mentioned and now its detected by the eclipse.